# env folder and requirements.txt and gitignore

Tags: python, django

I have env folder inside my project, and I'm thinking to include that in my gitignore. but after googling, I asw this is a bad idea. So I removed it from the project folder and located somewhere else. then I got an error saying the apps I need aren't included which I don't understand because I did pip freeze > requirements.txt

My question is can I just put env folder in gitignore?
and my folder structure is just typical one,

```
project1
-----project
-----app
-----manage.py
and I did gitinit when I'm in project1, is this correct?
```

Comment: Have you read the [help](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) to see if any of those solutions solve your problem? Mainly the sections on global and excludes

Comment: @idjaw I'm using https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Python.gitignore not sure if this is valid tho

Comment: What is in your env directory?